# What is 'import as'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

For example, in the following:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

**What is the relationship between `Router, Route, Switch` and `BrowserRouter`?** Is this a form of  destructuring?

If so, I thought destructuring was done using the following syntax:

```
  import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

  function App() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
       //...
      </Fragment>
    
    );
  }
```

Comment: You have really everything here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @Jayce444 that's really not helpful at all. I remember being confused by plenty of things that seem obvious in retrospect, now that I have knowledge that I didn't then.

Answer (score 4):

It is *very* similar to destructuring, though not exactly the same thing. The `as` keyword is a special one for when you want to import a *named export* of a library under a different name. (See below for more on named exports)

---

So when a library developer exports functions or whatever from their library, they write something like:

```js
export const someFunc = () => {};
export const someOtherFunc = () => {};
export const someThirdFunc = () => {};
```

These are called "named exports." They're what you're importing when you write something like

```js
import { someFunc } from 'some-library';
```

So what `as` does it lets you import that named export under a new name you've chosen.

```js
import { someFunc as somePreferredName, someOtherFunc as someOtherPreferredName, someThirdFunc } from 'some-library';
```

---

You can also import every named import into a single object like so:

```js
import * as someLibrary from 'some-library';
```

Then you can do something like `someLibrary.someFunc()`;

---

Or you can import the "default export." What exactly the default export contains is determined by the library's author, but usually the default export is equivalent to the syntax in the prior section of this answer.

So in the case of React, the two lines below are equivalent:

```js
// import React from 'react';
import * as React from 'react'; // Imports every named export of 'react' and put it into an object named React.
```

---

#### Bringing it all together

It's important to note that React in particular requires you to import the *default export*. This is not an ES6 import thing, it's a React v16.x requirement. For other packages you can import just a piece and it will function as intended.

Lodash is an easier example. For Lodash, importing the default export is equivalent to importing everything.

```js
// Import the named export "debounce" from 'lodash' into a variable of the same name
import { debounce } from 'lodash';



// Imports the named export "debounce" from 'lodash' into a variable of your chosen name
import { debounce as anyNameYouWant } from 'lodash' 



// Imports the default export of 'lodash' into the object named anyNameYouWant
import anyNameYouWant, { debounce } from 'lodash'; // And then additionally, imports debounce into a variable of the same name
```

Note that there is no 'as' keyword with default imports. They're not *named* exports, so when you import them, you're always choosing the name. That's what `as` allows you to do, but for named exports.

Comment: But, the OP showed an example with multiple names to the right of as: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'`.  How does that work?

Comment: @jfriend00 I was about to ask the same. And I would also like to point out that BrowserRouter.Router doesn't work, while React.Fragment DOES. Router, Route, Switch also have different uses as components.

Comment: So each one of those is a separate named export. I've updated with more examples - but if that doesn't answer your question let me know. @kennsorr the determining factor is how the library author exports things on their end AND how you import it. When you import React, that's called a "default export." In React's case the default export will contain every named export inside of the `React` object - but that's not necessarily going to be how the default export works for every library.

Comment: I think calling this destructuring is a mistake and confuses things. This is named import syntax, you're sort of destructuring the module namespace object, but since the bindings are live, it's not grabbing one singular value at import time like destructuring would.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think that's a fair point and I'll update my language.

Comment: You updated with an example `import {a as x, b as y, c as z} from 'lib'` which seems clear.  But, the OP asked about `import {a as x, y, z} from 'lib'`.  Is that even legal syntax?  If so, what does it do?

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah it's legal. Take a closer look at the second to last codeblock in my example and you'll note that the final import is not using `as`, like in OP's case. You can use `as` for as many or as few named imports as you'd like.

Comment: @Slbox - I think you should call out the specific example that the OP asked about as illegal syntax then.  Right now, it kind of looks like you just didn't answer the direct question they asked because you don't say anything about the actual example they asked about.

Comment: Yeah I see now I was focused on the difference in the use of `as`. I've tried to update the answer, but I think I'm going to have to come back to clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Javascript expert by any means but I think that is calling for more than one module to be imported.

Example I found from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import :

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";

import * as name from "module-name";

import { export1 } from "module-name";

import { export1 as alias1 } from "module-name";

import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";

import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";

import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";

import defaultExport, { export1 [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";

import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";

import "module-name";

var promise = import("module-name");
```